# enum case handling - better to use a switch or a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, switch-statement

When handling the values of an enum on a case by case basis, is it better to use a switch statement or a dictionary?

I would think that the dictionary would be faster.  In terms of space, it takes up some in memory, but the case statement would also take up some memory just in the memory needed for the program itself.  So bottom line I'm thinking it's always better to just use the dictionary.

Here are the two implementations side by side for comparison:

Given these enums:

```
enum FruitType
{
    Other,
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Mango,
    Orange
}
enum SpanishFruitType
{
    Otra,
    Manzana, // Apple
    Naranja, // Orange
    Platano, // Banana
    Pitaya // Dragon fruit, only grown in Mexico and South American countries, lets say
    // let's say they don't have mangos, because I don't remember the word for it.
}
```

Here is the way to do it with the switch statement:

```
private static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalent(FruitType typeOfFruit)
{
    switch(typeOfFruit)
    {
        case FruitType.Apple:
            return SpanishFruitType.Manzana;
        case FruitType.Banana:
            return SpanishFruitType.Platano;
        case FruitType.Orange:
            return SpanishFruitType.Naranja;
        case FruitType.Mango:
        case FruitType.Other:
            return SpanishFruitType.Otra;
        default:
            throw new Exception("what kind of fruit is " + typeOfFruit + "?!");
    }
}
```

And here is how it is done with a dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<FruitType, SpanishFruitType> EnglishToSpanishFruit = new Dictionary<FruitType, SpanishFruitType>()
{
    {FruitType.Apple, SpanishFruitType.Manzana}
    ,{FruitType.Banana, SpanishFruitType.Platano}
    ,{FruitType.Mango, SpanishFruitType.Otra}
    ,{FruitType.Orange, SpanishFruitType.Naranja}
    ,{FruitType.Other, SpanishFruitType.Otra}
};
private static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalentWithDictionary(FruitType typeOfFruit)
{
    return EnglishToSpanishFruit[typeOfFruit]; // throws exception if it's not in the dictionary, which is fine.
}
```

Not only does the dictionary have the speed boost, it also has less unnecessary strings in the code.  Is this always better to use the dictionary then?  Is there even a third better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many of these lookups are you doing per second? If it's anything less than a bajillion, don't worry about it. Just choose the method that is easiest for you to read/maintain.

Comment: Switch is faster in reality

Comment: Switch statement will be translated by the compiler into a "dictionary" (more precisely a hash) when it contains more than 7 options, so if it's more readable for you, use a switch statement and just let the compiler do his best for the optimizations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, a dictionary is slower. Really. Just write simple benchmark (I've added example with converting dictionary to array):

```
void Main()
{
    for (int itFac = 0; itFac < 7; itFac++ ) {
        var iterations = 100;
        iterations *= (int)Math.Pow(10, itFac);

        Console.WriteLine("Iterations: {0}", iterations);

        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int maxFruits = 5;
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                var res =  Fruits.GetSpanishEquivalentWithArray((Fruits.FruitType)r.Next(maxFruits));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Array time: {0}", timer.Elapsed);
        }       

        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int maxFruits = 5;
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                var res = Fruits.GetSpanishEquivalent((Fruits.FruitType)r.Next(maxFruits));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Switch time    : {0}", timer.Elapsed);
        }

        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int maxFruits = 5;
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                var res =  Fruits.GetSpanishEquivalentWithDictionary((Fruits.FruitType)r.Next(maxFruits));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary time: {0}", timer.Elapsed);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Fruits {
    public enum FruitType
    {
        Other,
        Apple,
        Banana,
        Mango,
        Orange
    }
    public enum SpanishFruitType
    {
        Otra,
        Manzana, // Apple
        Naranja, // Orange
        Platano, // Banana
        // let's say they don't have mangos, because I don't remember the word for it.
    }

    public static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalent(FruitType typeOfFruit)
    {
        switch(typeOfFruit)
        {
            case FruitType.Apple:
                return SpanishFruitType.Manzana;
            case FruitType.Banana:
                return SpanishFruitType.Platano;
            case FruitType.Orange:
                return SpanishFruitType.Naranja;
            case FruitType.Mango:
            case FruitType.Other:
                return SpanishFruitType.Otra;
            default:
                throw new Exception("what kind of fruit is " + typeOfFruit + "?!");
        }
    }

    public static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalent(string typeOfFruit)
    {
        switch(typeOfFruit)
        {
            case "apple":
                return SpanishFruitType.Manzana;
            case "banana":
                return SpanishFruitType.Platano;
            case "orange":
                return SpanishFruitType.Naranja;
            case "mango":
            case "other":
                return SpanishFruitType.Otra;
            default:
                throw new Exception("what kind of fruit is " + typeOfFruit + "?!");
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<FruitType, SpanishFruitType> EnglishToSpanishFruit = new Dictionary<FruitType, SpanishFruitType>()
    {
        {FruitType.Apple, SpanishFruitType.Manzana}
        ,{FruitType.Banana, SpanishFruitType.Platano}
        ,{FruitType.Mango, SpanishFruitType.Otra}
        ,{FruitType.Orange, SpanishFruitType.Naranja}
        ,{FruitType.Other, SpanishFruitType.Otra}
    };

    public static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalentWithDictionary(FruitType typeOfFruit)
    {
        return EnglishToSpanishFruit[typeOfFruit]; // throws exception if it's not in the dictionary, which is fine.
    }

    public static SpanishFruitType[] EnglishToSpanishFruitArray;

    static Fruits() {
        EnglishToSpanishFruitArray = new SpanishFruitType[EnglishToSpanishFruit.Select(p => (int)p.Key).Max() + 1];
        foreach (var pair in EnglishToSpanishFruit)
            EnglishToSpanishFruitArray[(int)pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }

    public static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalentWithArray(FruitType typeOfFruit)
    {
        return EnglishToSpanishFruitArray[(int)typeOfFruit]; // throws exception if it's not in the dictionary, which is fine.
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Iterations: 100
Array time     : 00:00:00.0108628
Switch time    : 00:00:00.0002204
Dictionary time: 00:00:00.0008475

Iterations: 1000
Array time     : 00:00:00.0000410
Switch time    : 00:00:00.0000472
Dictionary time: 00:00:00.0004556

Iterations: 10000
Array time     : 00:00:00.0006095
Switch time    : 00:00:00.0011230
Dictionary time: 00:00:00.0074769

Iterations: 100000
Array time     : 00:00:00.0043019
Switch time    : 00:00:00.0047117
Dictionary time: 00:00:00.0611122

Iterations: 1000000
Array time     : 00:00:00.0468998
Switch time    : 00:00:00.0520848
Dictionary time: 00:00:00.5861588

Iterations: 10000000
Array time     : 00:00:00.4268453
Switch time    : 00:00:00.5002004
Dictionary time: 00:00:07.5352484

Iterations: 100000000
Array time     : 00:00:04.1720282
Switch time    : 00:00:04.9347176
Dictionary time: 00:00:56.0107932
```

What happens. Let's look on the generated IL code:

```
Fruits.GetSpanishEquivalent:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  stloc.1     
IL_0003:  ldloc.1     
IL_0004:  switch      (IL_002B, IL_001F, IL_0023, IL_002B, IL_0027)
IL_001D:  br.s        IL_002F
IL_001F:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0020:  stloc.0     
IL_0021:  br.s        IL_004A
IL_0023:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0024:  stloc.0     
IL_0025:  br.s        IL_004A
IL_0027:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0028:  stloc.0     
IL_0029:  br.s        IL_004A
IL_002B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002C:  stloc.0     
IL_002D:  br.s        IL_004A
IL_002F:  ldstr       "what kind of fruit is "
IL_0034:  ldarg.0     
IL_0035:  box         UserQuery+Fruits.FruitType
IL_003A:  ldstr       "?!"
IL_003F:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0044:  newobj      System.Exception..ctor
IL_0049:  throw       
IL_004A:  ldloc.0     
IL_004B:  ret
```

What happens? [Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch.aspx) happens. For sequenced number of values switch can be optimized and replaced by jump to pointer from array. Why real array works faster than switch - dunno, it just works faster.

Well, if you do not work with enums, but with strings there is no real difference between switch and dictionary on small number of variants. With more and more variants dictionary becomes faster.

What to choose? Choose what is easier to read for you and your team. When you see that your solution creates performance issues you should replace Dictionary (if you use it) to switch or array like me. When your function of translation is rarely called there is no need to optimize it.

Talking about your case - to get translation, all solutions are bad. Translations must be stored in resources. There must be only one FruitType, no other enums.

Comment: Very nice.  The example was a bit contrived, instead of enum -> other enum it could have been enum -> Action.  What do you mean by "stored in resources" though?

Comment: @user420667 Line was started by "Talking about your case". Talking about translations. For all another cases this approach isn't applicable. About resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9za7fxc7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thre's so much wrong with this performance analysis I don't really know where to start. The stopwatch is not only measuring the time taken by the `Random` to generate each random number (which is orders of magnitude slower than the retrieval operations and swamps them), but different random numbers are being used for each run. Additionally, you are measuring the time taken to run the static constructor of `Fruits` in the first iteration of `Fruits.GetSpanishEquivalentWithArray`. This is why the 'Array time' is so large in the '100 Iterations' result.

Comment: If you rewrite the code to only measure the retrieval operations you'll find that an array lookup is always faster than a switch because the generated assembly is branchless. Conversely the switch will be compiled into a sequence of conditional branches (unless the number of cases is large in which case it'll be compiled to a jump table). The gotcha with using array lookups though is that Enum elements can take any integral value. You'll need to handle the edge cases (e.g. an enum with an underlying `long` data type or negative values etc).

Comment: Added another answer which outlines an optimal generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since the translations are one-to-one or one-to-none, why not assign IDs to each word. Then cast from one enum to another

So define your enums as

```
enum FruitType
{
    Other = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Mango = 3,
    Orange = 4
}
enum SpanishFruitType
{
    Otra = 0,
    Manzana = 1, // Apple
    Platano = 2, // Banana
    Naranja = 4, // Orange
}
```

Then define your conversion method as

```
private static SpanishFruitType GetSpanishEquivalent(FruitType typeOfFruit)
{
    //'translate' with the word's ID. 
    //If there is no translation, the enum would be undefined
    SpanishFruitType translation = (SpanishFruitType)(int)typeOfFruit;

    //Check if the translation is defined
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SpanishFruitType), translation))
    {
        return translation;
    }
    else
    {
        return SpanishFruitType.Otra;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess in this particular scenario, this would probably be a good approach.  However, and I should have probably put this in the question, but there could be Spanish enums that have no meaning in English, in which case the one-to-one or one-to-none-ness is gone.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your scenario but, as an alternative, you could just have an attribute containing the translated text.

```
public enum FruitType
{
   [Description("Otra")]
   Other,
   [Description("Manzana")]
   Apple,            
   [Description("Platano")]
   Banana,      
   Mango,
   [Description("Naranja")]
   Orange
}
```

Then you can have a method to read the description

```
public static string GetTranslation(FruitType fruit)
{
    var mi = typeof(FruitType).GetMember(fruit.ToString());
    var attr = mi[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),false);
    if (attr.Count() > 0)
        return ((DescriptionAttribute)attr[0]).Description;
    else
        return fruit.ToString(); //if no description added, return the original fruit
}
```

So you can then call it like this

```
string translated = GetTranslation(FruitType.Apple);
```

Since it uses reflection, this is likely to be the least efficient but might be easier to maintain depending on your situation and, as Chris mentioned in the comments, may not have any noticeable impact depending on how often it's called. You can swap `Description` for a custom attribute of course. Just another option for you to consider :)

Comment: Nah, bad idea. There are different descriptions for diffrent languages

Comment: @nsinreal - Enums can have multiple attributes (`DescriptionAttribute` doesn't but there's no reason why a custom attribute with `AllowMultiple` set to `true` couldn't work). Admittedly it might not be as performant (although whether it's noticeable needs to be tested) but it means there's only one source of update required.

Comment: That's bad idea anyway. Translations must be in resources, not in code.

Comment: @nsinreal But how does this differ from any of OP's suggestions? I'd argue that, short of accessing the resource files directly to perform the translation, it's easier to replace the strings within the attributes with strings from resource files than to replace enums within a dictionary or switch statement from a resource file.

Comment: who says that original solutions are nice? You must say some additional info, nop? But author's code a bit diffent: it's about conversion enum to enum, not about conversin enum to string. I don't know how author choosed fruits - or he have real need of descripting fruits (possibly no), or he showed just an example for thinking about it. What is original task - to convert enum to enum; or enum to string - that's info is unknow.

Comment: about your code: I think, if we need to make it fast, we must make static constructor in class of GetTranslation, static constructor must find out descriptions of each item in enumeration and write it somewhere. That's info is generally for user420667.

Comment: I don't think the description approach is for me, since the word "description" itself is a bit vague, and the use of it would rapidly get ugly if we had other translations.  Interesting thought though.

Comment: @nsinreal - There's no reason the attribute couldn't return an enum instead of a string but I agree that in this case the resource file is the easiest route to go.

Comment: @user420667 - `Description` is just the built in attribute but you can create your own and call it `Spanish`, then have one for `French` etc.. But this was just to show you an alternative approach, which could also be used for non-translation apps like the dictionary/switch approaches, but as nsinreal said, resource files may make most sense in this particular case.

Comment: @user420667 think about this idea a little bit more. You can write your own attribute and write all stuff about your enum just in your enum, near each element. That can be more clearly than ugly dictionary or switch :-)

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be looking for the fastest method of retrieving an item which is mapped to an `Enum` constant.

The underlying type for almost all `Enum` types, which are not bit fields (i.e. not declared as `[Flags]`), is a 32-bit signed integer. There are sound performance reasons for this. The only real reason to use something different is if you absolutely **must** minimise memory usage. Bit fields are a different matter but we're not concerned with them here.

In this typical scenario, an array map is ideal (and usually faster than a `switch`). Here's some generic code which is concise and optimised for retrieval. Unfortunately, due to the limitations of .NET generic constraints, a few hacks are required (such as having to pass a casting delegate into the instance constructor).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace DEMO
{
    public sealed class EnumMapper<TKey, TValue> where TKey : struct, IConvertible
    {
        private struct FlaggedValue<T>
        {
            public bool flag;
            public T value;
        }

        private static readonly int size;
        private readonly Func<TKey, int> func;
        private FlaggedValue<TValue>[] flaggedValues;

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                int index = this.func.Invoke(key);

                FlaggedValue<TValue> flaggedValue = this.flaggedValues[index];

                if (flaggedValue.flag == false)
                {
                    EnumMapper<TKey, TValue>.ThrowNoMappingException(); // Don't want the exception code in the method. Make this callsite as small as possible to promote JIT inlining and squeeze out every last bit of performance.
                }

                return flaggedValue.value;
            }
        }

        static EnumMapper()
        {
            Type keyType = typeof(TKey);

            if (keyType.IsEnum == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("The key type [" + keyType.AssemblyQualifiedName + "] is not an enumeration.");
            }

            Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(keyType);

            if (underlyingType != typeof(int))
            {
                throw new Exception("The key type's underlying type [" + underlyingType.AssemblyQualifiedName + "] is not a 32-bit signed integer.");
            }

            var values = (int[])Enum.GetValues(keyType);

            int maxValue = 0;

            foreach (int value in values)
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The key type has a constant with a negative value.");
                }

                if (value > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = value;
                }
            }

            EnumMapper<TKey, TValue>.size = maxValue + 1;
        }

        public EnumMapper(Func<TKey, int> func)
        {
            if (func == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("func",
                                                "The func cannot be a null reference.");
            }

            this.func = func;

            this.flaggedValues = new FlaggedValue<TValue>[EnumMapper<TKey, TValue>.size];
        }

        public static EnumMapper<TKey, TValue> Construct(Func<TKey, int> func)
        {
            return new EnumMapper<TKey, TValue>(func);
        }

        public EnumMapper<TKey, TValue> Map(TKey key,
                                            TValue value)
        {
            int index = this.func.Invoke(key);

            FlaggedValue<TValue> flaggedValue;

            flaggedValue.flag = true;
            flaggedValue.value = value;

            this.flaggedValues[index] = flaggedValue;

            return this;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void ThrowNoMappingException()
        {
            throw new Exception("No mapping exists corresponding to the key.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then simply initialise the mappings using a nice fluent interface:

```
var mapper = EnumMapper<EnumType, ValueType>.Construct((x) => (int)x)
                                            .Map(EnumType.Constant1, value1)
                                            .Map(EnumType.Constant2, value2)
                                            .Map(EnumType.Constant3, value3)
                                            .Map(EnumType.Constant4, value4)
                                            .Map(EnumType.Constant5, value5);
```

And easily retrieve the mapped value:

```
ValueType value = mapper[EnumType.Constant3];
```

The x86 assembly (generated using the Visual Studio 2013 compiler) for the retrieval method is minimal:

```
000007FE8E9909B0  push        rsi  
000007FE8E9909B1  sub         rsp,20h  
000007FE8E9909B5  mov         rsi,rcx  
000007FE8E9909B8  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsi+8]  
000007FE8E9909BC  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rax+8]  
000007FE8E9909C0  call        qword ptr [rax+18h]  // The casting delegate's callsite is optimised to just two instructions 
000007FE8E9909C3  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rsi+10h]  
000007FE8E9909C7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rdx+8]  
000007FE8E9909CA  cmp         eax,ecx  
000007FE8E9909CC  jae         000007FE8E9909ED  
000007FE8E9909CE  movsxd      rax,eax  
000007FE8E9909D1  lea         rax,[rdx+rax*8+10h]  
000007FE8E9909D6  movzx       edx,byte ptr [rax]  
000007FE8E9909D9  mov         esi,dword ptr [rax+4]  
000007FE8E9909DC  test        dl,dl  
000007FE8E9909DE  jne         000007FE8E9909E5  
000007FE8E9909E0  call        000007FE8E9901B8  
000007FE8E9909E5  mov         eax,esi  
000007FE8E9909E7  add         rsp,20h  
000007FE8E9909EB  pop         rsi  
000007FE8E9909EC  ret  
000007FE8E9909ED  call        000007FEEE411A08  
000007FE8E9909F2  int         3
```