# Is there any more efficient way to return a string based on a number passed to a method?

Tags: c#

I coded this method to meet my needs. There are three more case values here but I did not include them.

```
    public static string scoreColumn(int num)
    {
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1: return "English";
            case 2: return "Kanji"; 
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Can someone tell me is this an optimal and clean way to return a string in this method. Am I missing a more obvious and simple way of achieving the same functionality?

Comment: yes. more efficient way is to use Dictionary if you have lot of cases

Comment: U didn't use break ?

Comment: there is no need for break when there`s return @Kshitiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever is easier to use and read, and worry about efficiency only when needed.

```
string[] scoreColumn = { "English", "Kanji" }; 

string result = scoreColumn.ElementAtOrDefault(num - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

An array of strings would do the trick for me instead of writing a new method.

Comment: Can you give me a very short example of what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dictionary for this purpose.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1,"abc" },
    {2,"efg" },
    //...
};

public static string scoreColumn(int num)
{
    string val;
    if(dic.TryGetValue(num, out val)) return val;
    else return "";
}
```

For larger number of cases dictionary will perform better. for small amount of cases using dictionary shouldn't be a problem either. also with dictionary you can manage your cases easier as you can see.

Comment: I would recommend testing before assuming that something is more efficient http://stackoverflow.com/a/17605914/1383168

Comment: @Slai I copied the exact same code from that answer and dictionary performed faster on my computer.

Comment: @Slai its strange... did you see that `56` seconds in last result?!! for me it finished in `1.8` seconds! switch finished in `2.5` seconds. After I compiled in release mode to enable optimizations both finished in `1.6` seconds. they performed same. btw using array indexer is the fastest so +1 :)

Comment: Oh nice, I guess the new Roslyn Compiler in VS 2015 improved a lot. On my Intel i5, VS 2015 Release I got 2.2 array, 3.4 switch, 4.3 Dictionary. When I replaced the randoms with a number, the Dictionary was about 9 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, an `enum` would be a better choice compared to an integer, and since your descriptions have no whitespace you could just output the enumeration name using `.ToString()`.

If you wanted to get even fancier you can add attributes to enumeration members, but getting them out requires some reflection trickery.  You can encapsulate this an extension method, but it's a kind of ugly one.

See http://www.codeducky.org/ins-outs-c-enums/ for some examples (the last example is using an attribute, they also show the .ToString() approach).